# Generate blocks of Python code with for loop

Tags: python, code-generation, pygtk

I made a small GUI program with PyGtk for parametrically drawing the frame of a bike (the idea: you move some slider, and the frame gets redrawn with the updated parameter).

Somewhere in the code, I must create a slider for each parameter, and I get this very non-pythonic and repetitive code (sorry, I could not get the indentation right while writing this message):

```
def adjustbottomBracketHeight(par):
    BikeDrawing.p.bottomBracketHeight = par.get_value()
    painelhoriz.queue_draw()
bottomBracketHeightAdjust = gtk.Adjustment(value=BikeDrawing.p.bottomBracketHeight, lower=180., upper=400., step_incr=10.)
bbhScale = gtk.HScale(adjustment=bottomBracketHeightAdjust)
bbhScale.set_value_pos(gtk.POS_LEFT)
bbhScale.connect("value-changed", adjustbottomBracketHeight)
bbhLabel = gtk.Label("Bottom bracket height")
topcolumn1.pack_start(bbhLabel, False, False)
topcolumn1.pack_start(bbhScale, True, True)

def adjustseatTubeAngle(par):
    BikeDrawing.p.seatTubeAngle = par.get_value()
    painelhoriz.queue_draw()    
seatTubeAngleAdjust = gtk.Adjustment(value=BikeDrawing.p.seatTubeAngle, lower=60., upper=85., step_incr=0.5)
staScale = gtk.HScale(adjustment=seatTubeAngleAdjust)
staScale.set_value_pos(gtk.POS_LEFT)
staScale.connect("value-changed", adjustseatTubeAngle)
staLabel = gtk.Label("Seat tube angle")
topcolumn1.pack_start(staLabel, False, False)
topcolumn1.pack_start(staScale, True, True)

def adjustSeatTubeLength(par):
    BikeDrawing.p.seatTubeLength = par.get_value()
    painelhoriz.queue_draw()
seatTubeLengthAdjust = gtk.Adjustment(value=BikeDrawing.p.seatTubeLength, lower=300., upper=700., step_incr=10.)
stlScale = gtk.HScale(adjustment=seatTubeLengthAdjust)
stlScale.set_value_pos(gtk.POS_LEFT)
stlScale.connect("value-changed", adjustSeatTubeLength)
topcolumn1.pack_start(stlScale, True, True)

def adjusttopTubeLength(par):
    BikeDrawing.p.topTubeLength = par.get_value()
    painelhoriz.queue_draw()
topTubeLengthAdjust = gtk.Adjustment(value=BikeDrawing.p.topTubeLength,
    lower=400., upper=700., step_incr=10.)
ttlScale = gtk.HScale(adjustment=topTubeLengthAdjust)
ttlScale.set_value_pos(gtk.POS_LEFT)
ttlScale.connect("value-changed", adjusttopTubeLength)
topcolumn1.pack_start(ttlScale, True, True)
```

Well with some minor adaptations, I would like (to know how ;o) to "create" this kind of code iterating over a list of the parameter names, something similar to:

```
par_list = ['bottomBracketHeight', 'seatTubeAngle', 'seatTubeHeight']
def widgetize(PARAMETER):
    """ Create blocks of code where the name PARAMETER would be used to personalize names of handlers, functions, objects, etc. """

for par in par_list:
    widgetize(par)
```

I read some previous questions/answers and there seems not to be an answer to this specific problem.

I appreciate very much your attention

Comment: I had this post edited (thanks, delnan!), but actually only the first two lines after each def belong to the def itself, others are out of the def block. Anyway, it does not change (much) the intent of the task automation, I think.

Comment: Edited again, is it correct now?

Comment: Now the indentation is fine! Thanks for helping, @delnan, and sorry for being so n00b... :oP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is more or less what you're after:

```
def makeAdjuster(name, attr, lower, upper, step):
    def doAdjust(par):
        setattr(Bikedrawing.p, attr, par.get_value())
        panelhoriz.queue_draw()

    val = getattr(Bikedrawing.p, attr)
    adjust = gtk.Adjustment(value=val, lower=lower, upper=upper, step_incr=step)

    label = gtk.Label(name)
    topcolumn1.pack_start(label, False, False)

    scale = gtk.HScale(adjustment=adjust)
    scale.set_value_pos(gtk.POS_LEFT)
    scale.connect("value-changed", doAdjust)
    topcolumn1.pack_start(scale, True, True)

for adj in (
    ('Bottom bracket height', 'bottomBracketHeight', 180., 400., 10.),
    ('Seat tube angle', 'seatTubeAngle', 60., 80., 0.5),
    ('Seat tube length', 'seatTubeLength', 300., 700., 10.),
    ('Top tube length', 'topTubeLength', 400., 700., 10.)
):
    makeAdjuster(*adj)
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you:

```
def widgetize(parameter):
    def handler(par):
        setattr(BikeDrawing.p, parameter, par.get_value()
        painelhoriz.queue_draw()

    adjust = gtk.Adjustment(value=getattr(BikeDrawing.p, parameter), lower=300., upper=700., step_incr=10.)
    stlScale = gtk.HScale(adjustment=adjust)
    stlScale.set_value_pos(gtk.POS_LEFT)
    stlScale.connect("value-changed", handler)
    topcolumn1.pack_start(stlScale, True, True)
```

You might want to pass some other parameters such as BikeDrawing.p in to widgetize also.

Note that there's no need to customise local names for objects or the names of functions, only the names of attributes matter here. For more general code use more general function and object names.

Answer (score 2):

This higher-order function creates the functions for you. But you'll need to make sure variables like `painelhoriz` and `BikeDrawing` are either in scope for the definition or pass them manually.

```
def widgetize(name, needsLabel = False, labelText = None):
    def adjust(par):
        val = par.get_value()
        setattr(BikeDrawing.p, name, val)
        painelhoriz.queue_draw()
        adjustment = gtk.Adjustment(value=val, lower=180., upper=400., step_incr=10.0)
        scale = gtk.HScale(adjustment=adjustment)
        scale.set_value_pos(gtk.POS_LEFT)
        scale.connect("value-changed", adjust)
        if needsLabel:
            label = gtk.Label(labelText)
            topcolumn1.pack_start(Label, False, False)
        topcolumn1.pack_start(scale, True, True)
    # add nice name for debugging
    adjust.__name__ = "adjust{}".format(name[0].upper() + name[1:])
    return adjust
```

One remark: You seem to mix up generation of widgets with adjustment of attributes and per-frame-drawing. As is, the code will generate all the widgets anew every time one changes...

Comment: Yes, actually I could not indent the code properly, only the two lines after each def is inside the def scope, the rest is global and runs only once.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question literally — `exec`. But this should be reserved when other options are not viable, and your code can easily be refactored to be more generic. Look into `getattr` and `setattr`, i.e. instead of `BikeDrawing.p.something = foo` do `setattr(BikeDrawing.p, 'something', foo)` — you can then use a variable for the attribute name, similarly with accessing attributes and `getattr`. It's all about finding patterns (and you have a lot of them — creating `Adjustment`/`HScale` instances, setting `BikeDrawing.p`), and moving code around.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use introspection, something like:

```
for par in par_list:
    value=getattr(BikeDrawing.p, par)
    # ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest wrapping it into a class that knows how to manage/draw itself. You would still need to either pass in the attribute name to modify (`"bottomBracketHeight"` for example) and use `getattr`/`setattr` on `BikeDrawing.p` (or you could even just store them as instance variables of this new class if no other code touches these values!), and each class would get their own `HScale` and `Label` to manipulate.